# SQL query returning rows while executing it on SQL dedveloper but is not working in the PLSQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the procedure

```
    PROCEDURE NON_BLOCKING_STATUS
IS
    cursor badcur is    
    select query;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('sch_id    sch_revision  SCD_SEQUENCE  SCH_STATUS   scD_status  scd_action  scd_object SCD_NAME    scl_text');
    for badrow in badcur LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line ( badrow.sch_id || ' ' || badrow.sch_revision || ' ' || badrow.SCD_SEQUENCE || ' ' || badrow.SCH_STATUS || ' ' || badrow.scD_status || ' ' || badrow.scd_action || ' ' || badrow.scd_object || ' ' || badrow.SCD_NAME || ' ' || badrow.scl_text);
    end loop;
end;
```

The select sql query is returning rows while running it on SQL developer but while using it in the above procedure, its not working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you run `set serveroutput on` before calling the procedure?

Comment: Was the heading printed?

Comment: Yes i have already added that {set serveroutput on} and the heading was printed but when i am trying to print that heading inside the loop, its not printed.

Comment: Do you have an Oracle error?

Comment: How are you executing the procedure - also from SQL Developer, in the same session? If not do you have uncommitted data, which will only be visible from the session that created it?